# Div moving away when the window gets resized

Tags: html, css

i have the following div on my site

```
 <div id="div"></div>


 #div {
        
        height: 400px;
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 59%;
        text-align: left;

    }
```

But if the page get´s resized, the div is moving away.
Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: you would require a parent div with relative position.

Comment: Moving away from what?

Answer (score 1):

because you use %.
you need to position right to something else like:

```
<div id="parent"> <div id=div> Text </div></div>

#parent{
     position:relative;
     width:100% //you can decide.
}
#div {
    
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20rem;
    text-align: left;

}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but that doesnt work, the div is still moving away

Comment: did you give a position relative to the parent div?

Comment: thanks, but the div is still moving if the windows gets smaller

Answer (score 0):

According to W3C, the right property sets the right edge of an element to a unit to the right of the right edge of its nearest positioned ancestor. In your case, the ancestor is body, so when you resize your window, the width of window change so it push the div to 59% to the right side